# In mongo, how do I use map reduce to get a group by ordered by most recent

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, greatest-n-per-group

the map reduce examples I see use aggregation functions like count, but what is the best way to get say the top 3 items in each category using map reduce.

I'm assuming I can also use the group function but was curious since they state sharded environments cannot use group().  However, I'm actually interested in seeing a group() example as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of simplification, I'll assume you have documents of the form:

```
{category: <int>, score: <int>}
```

I've created 1000 documents covering 100 categories with:

```
for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  db.foo.save({
    category: parseInt(Math.random() * 100),
    score: parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
  });
}
```

Our mapper is pretty simple, just emit the category as key, and an object containing an array of scores as the value:

```
mapper = function () {
  emit(this.category, {top:[this.score]});
}
```

MongoDB's reducer cannot return an array, and the reducer's output must be of the same type as the values we `emit`, so we must wrap it in an object. We need an array of scores, as this will let our reducer compute the top 3 scores:

```
reducer = function (key, values) {
  var scores = [];
  values.forEach(
    function (obj) {
      obj.top.forEach(
        function (score) {
          scores[scores.length] = score;
      });
  });
  scores.sort();
  scores.reverse();
  return {top:scores.slice(0, 3)};
}
```

Finally, invoke the map-reduce:

```
db.foo.mapReduce(mapper, reducer, "top_foos");
```

Now we have a collection containing one document per category, and the top 3 scores across all documents from `foo` in that category:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "value" : { "top" : [ 93, 89, 86 ] } }
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : { "top" : [ 82, 65, 6 ] } }
```

(Your exact values may vary if you used the same `Math.random()` data generator as I have above)

You can now use this to query `foo` for the actual documents having those top scores:

```
function find_top_scores(categories) {
  var query = [];
  db.top_foos.find({_id:{$in:categories}}).forEach(
    function (topscores) {
      query[query.length] = {
        category:topscores._id,
        score:{$in:topscores.value.top}
      };
  });
  return db.foo.find({$or:query});
```

}

This code won't handle ties, or rather, if ties exist, more than 3 documents might be returned in the final cursor produced by `find_top_scores`.

The solution using `group` would be somewhat similar, though the reducer will only have to consider two documents at a time, rather than an array of scores for the key.