# Find max of groups with common field without discarding the whole document in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have a collection in my database and I have managed to write an aggregation pipeline that returns this kind of results: 
`ip, type, count` 
where `ip, type` are the fields I grouped by and `count` the number of these pairs found in my collection. 
How can I now only keep the pairs `ip, type` where `count` is maximum for all ips? 
e.g.

```
ip1, type1, 10
ip1, type2, 20
ip1, type3, 30
ip2, type1, 30
ip2, type2, 10
```

From these 3, I only want to keep ip1, type3 because 30 is the max for all types of ip1 and ip2, type1 because 30 is max for all types of ip2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run another `$group` in order to get `maxCount`. All the documents belonging to a single group can be captured using a `$$ROOT` variable. Then you can run [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to find the one that has highest value and use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote that doc back to root level of your result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.ip",
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            maxCount: { $max: "$count" }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayElemAt: [ { "$filter": { input: "$docs", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.count", "$maxCount" ] } } } ,0]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/06ZIEhIroNU)

Comment: There could also be other ips in there and their counts would get in the way. I want the type for every ip where the type was found in a maximum count "row"

Comment: @TheoStefou - I see, gimme a sec and please edit your question in the meantime

Comment: Thank you for the answer, give me some time to reflect on this, I am new to mongodb.

Comment: Alright, this actually works, thank you. Any ideas on how this could be changed to get the n greatest types instead of just the first one?

Comment: @TheoStefou take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41527265/6238977